# Angular - ngOnChanges with two attributs

Tags: angular, typescript

i pass two attributs from parent component to child component, and in the child component i used ngOnChnage function to get the data
the problem is when i display the data of exerciceFramework before the if statement, i get the data, but inside the if it doesn't display the data

```
 <ef-identifiers [exerciceFramework]="(exerciseFramework$ | async)" 
                 [professionType]="(professionType$ | async)"></ef-identifiers>

export class IdentifiersComponent implements OnChanges {

    @Input()
    public exerciceFramework: object;

    @Input()
    public professionType: string;

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        console.log(changes["exerciceFramework"]); // line 25
        if (changes["professionType"] && changes["professionType"].currentValue) {
            console.log(changes["exerciceFramework"]); // undefined line 27
        }
   }
```

Comment: What's the first output? You do realize, that the if-condition isn't bound to "exerciceFramework", but "professionType", right?

Comment: output in the console is as follows: i get currentValue null in the line 25, then undefined in the line 25, then undefined in the line 27, then i get the data in currentValue in the line 25

Comment: @PhilippMeissner when i put them in the same if condition like this  `if (changes["exerciceFramework"] && changes["professionType"] && changes["exerciceFramework"].currentValue && changes["professionType"].currentValue) { } `, the if condition returns false

Comment: You check professionType but try output exerciceFramework... may be you need check exerciceFramework